# Amount of possible alignments between a sequence and a sequence of spans

Tags: combinatorics

I have a sequence of $n$ balls and a sequence of $m$ buckets/lists/queues/... First, I split the $n$ balls into a sequence of spans by adding any amount of separators. Then, I assign each span to one or no bucket. Every bucket can hold one or no span, and the order of spans is preserved in the buckets (span $i_1$ is assigned to bucket $j_1$ and span $i_2$ is assigned to bucket $j_2$ then $i_1 < i_2$ iff $j_1 < j_2$).

How many different alignments can be created by the above process? (I don't know the correct combinatorics terminology or reference problems, so feel free to rephrase in more common parlance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that *any amount of separators* here means that you want to solve the problem for an arbitrary but **fixed** amount $p$ of separators. If you would also allow the value of $p$ to vary, and hence you want to compute the total number of different alignments that can be created when you can also choose the number of separators to be used, the solution at the end can just be summed over all possible values of $p$. I'll also assume that it is not allowed to place more than one separator between any pair of adjoining balls.

Let's start by dividing the problem into two more managable subproblems. The first problem is to compute the number of ways we can split the $n$ balls into sequences of $p+1$ spans. The second problems is to compute the number of ways we can assign a sequence of $p+1$ spans to $m$ buckets. Note that both processes (the splitting of the $n$ balls into a sequence of spans and the assigning of a sequence of spans to $m$ buckets) happen independently of each other and as such, by the multiplication principle, we can simply multiply both results to obtain our final result. If you're unfamiliar with this principle, a link to the Wikipedia page can be found below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

So let's tackle the first problem: we want to compute the number of ways we can split $n$ balls into sequences of $p+1$ spans or alternatively, we want to compute the number of ways we can place our $p$ separators between the balls. Since we have $n$ balls, there are $n-1$ places to put our $p$ separators. Hence, we need to choose $p$ places out of $n-1$ places (note that the order of selection does not matter). The amount of ways we can do this is given precisely by the combination

\begin{equation} \binom{n-1}{p}. \end{equation}

Now let's tackle the second problem, which is a bit more challenging since there is also the option of leaving a bucket empty. When faced with difficult problems in combinatorics, it is often a good approach to start by making the problem a bit more concrete and then generalizing the answer to the more general setting (arguably, this is a good problem solving technique in general). Therefore, suppose that we label each bucket in advance, either with the label "will contain a span of balls" or "will not contain a span of balls" and furthermore, suppose that we are dealing with a sequence of $m$ buckets of which $A$ have the label "will contain a span of balls". By the same reasoning as in the first subproblem, we can immediately see that there are precisely

\begin{equation} \binom{m}{A} \end{equation}

of such sequences of buckets. Also note already that if $A$ is the number of buckets that will contain a span of balls, then $A$ must be smaller than or equal to $p+1$, as otherwise we cannot fill each bucket that is assigned to contain a span of balls with a span of balls. Again by the same reasoning as in the first subproblem, it can be seen that there are

\begin{equation} \binom{p+1}{A} \end{equation}

ways to select $A$ spans out of a sequence of $p+1$ spans put in the $A$ buckets that are assigned to contain them. Therefore, as a preliminary result, we have that for any fixed amount $A \in \{0, 1, \dots, \min(m, p+1)\}$ of buckets that will contain a span of balls in a sequence of length $m$, there are

\begin{equation} \binom{p+1}{A}\binom{m}{A} \end{equation}

possibilities to make such an assignment as described in the question (each span is assigned to one or no bucket and every bucket is assigned to one or no span).

Now is probably a good time to address the additional specification that the order of spans in the buckets should be preserved. Luckily for us, this specification actually makes the problem easier (at least given the approach that we take here). Indeed, we can just assign the first span of balls to the first bucket in the sequence that is labelled to contain a span of balls, the second span of balls to the second bucket in the sequences labelled to contain a span of balls, etc. Obviously, there is only $1$ such assignment possible, hence we should multiply our previously obtained preliminary result by $1$. For the sake of clarity: suppose that this condition did not have to hold and we could assign any span in the sequence to any bucket, we would have to multiply the preliminary result by $A!$.

Now we are on the home strecth. Suppose that we $A$ is no longer fixed but it can take any value in $\{0, 1, \dots, \min(m, p+1)\}$, then the total number of possible assignments of $p+1$ spans to $m$ buckets becomes

\begin{equation} \sum_{A=0}^{\min(m, p+1)} \binom{p+1}{A}\binom{m}{A} \end{equation}

Therefore as a final result, we obtain that there are

\begin{equation} \binom{n-1}{p}\sum_{A=0}^{\min(m, p+1)} \binom{p+1}{A}\binom{m}{A} \end{equation}

possible alignments.